# Possible breach of the copyrights of the stack exchange inc?

Tags: discussion

So, I recently happen to visit this site: http://www.drupalla.com, and found it to be the amazingly similar to the Drupal Answers site. Moreover, it is similar to the design of the StackExchange network of sites.

To check this, I created a account on that site (used Google chrome to translate the site, as it is in Chinese language) and checked the features and found that its has almost the same features as the StackExchange sites.

It makes me feel good that one can use Drupal to built this type of sites, but I find it morally wrong.

Also on every page of any StackExchange site the following line appears at the very bottom:

> site design / logo © 2012 stack exchange inc; ...

So, I feel this is a issue of copyrights infringement, which should be taken care of.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: @Clive - So, can these sites stay as they are _legally_?

Comment: @indrock I don't know much about US IP law so I can't really answer that I'm afraid. I've heard of SE taking action against sites before (there's also a post on MSO with a list of infringers somewhere but I can't find it right now). I'll try to find that post and let you know, as I recall there are instructions on what to do if you feel strongly enough about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design is very similar, but it is not the same, and that site doesn't use the Stack Exchange logo.

There could be an infringement of the [Creative Commons - Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license if

- The questions shown in that site are copied from any Stack Exchange site
- There isn't any reference to that fact
- There isn't a link to the original question
- There aren't links to the user accounts on the Stack Exchange site, for the user who asked the question, or for the users who answered it